# AngularJS inside a service function this returns null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a service and I am trying to create a recursive function:

```
function(angular){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('main')
        .service('testRecursionService', function () {return {
                'factorial': function(data){
                    if(data = 1){
                        return data
                    }
                     else{
                         return data * this.factorial(data - 1);
                     }

                }}})}(angular.window)
```

When I call the factorial function inside a controller, it says this is undefined. I am from Java/C# background, so my understanding is service object is created by the injector and from then on I should be able to call the factorial function.

But how is this undefined? Am I missing something?

Comment: @skubski You can use this in a service though. I do it all the time.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You were right: the execution context remains the same in object declaration. I forgot about this exeception. Got to love JS. ;)

Comment: @skubski Yep, it's a wonderful language :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'use strict';

function(angular) { 

angular.module('main')
  .service('testRecursionService', function () {
    return {
      factorial: function(data){
        if(data === 1){
          return data;
        }
        else {
          return data * this.factorial(data - 1);
        }
      }
    };
  });
}(angular.window);
```

The issue should be that you had your function name (`factorial`) in quotation marks, thus saying it's undefined.

Also you need to change the `=` into `===` in your `if` statement. Or you assign `data` to be `1` instead of checking that it's `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use quotation marks around property names but I don't think that should have caused the problem. Also, I think you need to use '===' instead of the assignment operator in your conditional.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VDPeDhEFtY9mtil3Xw4h?p=preview)

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('main', []);

app.service('RecursionService', function (){

    var service = {
      'factorial': factorial
    };


    return service; 
    ////////////////////

    function factorial(data){

      // not '=' as this always be true
      if(data === 1){
          return data;
      }

      return data * this.factorial(data - 1);

    }

});

app.controller('foo', foo);

foo.$inject = ['$scope', 'RecursionService'];

function foo($scope, RecursionService){

  $scope.number = {
    value: 1

  };

  $scope.getResult = function(num){
    $scope.result = RecursionService.factorial(num);
  }

  $scope.getResult($scope.number.value);

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="main" >
    <div ng-controller="foo">
      <input type="text" ng-model="number.value" ng-change="getResult(number.value)">
      {{result}}
      </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: No need to complicate the service declaration tbh, it makes it more unreadable.